# Preciso de explicação no erro neste script em C++

Tags: c++, struct, enums

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Brinquedos{

enum Objetos {Bola, Carrinho, Caixa, Dinamite};


void func(int st_Bola, int st_Carrinho, int st_Caixa, int st_Dinamite){

   Bola=st_Bola;
   Carrinho=st_Carrinho;
   Caixa=st_Caixa;
   Dinamite=st_Dinamite;

    }

};

int main(){

    Brinquedos Insere;
    Brinquedos Mostra;

    Insere.func(10,9,15,25);

    std::cout << Mostra.Bola << Mostra.Carrinho << Mostra.Caixa << Mostra.Dinamite;



}
```

O erro é o seguinte:

> In member function 'void Brinquedos::func(int, int, int, int)': 11:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment 12:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment 13:13: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment 14:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Answer (score 8):

C++ não é uma linguagem de *script*. Esse código não faz sentido, acho que não quer usar uma enumeração. Se quer, todo o resto está errado. Na verdade acho que deseja criar um construtor então seria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Brinquedo {
    int Objetos;
    int Bola;
    int Carrinho;
    int Caixa;
    int Dinamite;
    void func(int st_Bola, int st_Carrinho, int st_Caixa, int st_Dinamite) {
        Bola = st_Bola;
        Carrinho = st_Carrinho;
        Caixa = st_Caixa;
        Dinamite = st_Dinamite;
    }
};

int main() {
    Brinquedo brinquedo;
    //não fazia sentido ter as duas variáveis aqui, cada uma fazendo algo totalmente diferente
    brinquedo.func(10,9,15,25);
    std::cout << brinquedo.Bola << brinquedo.Carrinho << brinquedo.Caixa << brinquedo.Dinamite;
}
```

Fiz alguma alterações cosméticas que ajudam dar legibilidade ao código.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/MPv1Jj). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wpgtuets-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Struct.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

`error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Isso significa que você está tentando salvar um número em um lugar impossível de salvar. Acontece que `enum` é para criar enumeração, ou seja, você criará constantes com nomes e que podem ser sequenciados.

Por exemplo,

`enum DiaDaSemana { dom , seg , ter , qua , qui , sex , sab } ;`

é enumeração de dias da semana, onde `DiaDaSemana::dom` representa o domingo, é o primeiro e portanto é o menor, fazer `(int)(DiaDaSemana::dom)` retorna `0`. Eles seguem uma sequência: `DiaDaSemana::dom` é zero e domingo, `DiaDaSemana::seg` é um e segunda, `DiaDaSemana::ter` é dois e terça-feira, daí em diante.

Isso significa que tentar fazer `DiaDaSemana::dom = 1 ;` é a mesma coisa que tentar setar a constante zero igual a um, o que é erro semântico por ser incoerente. Sendo assim, no seu caso o esquema é o mesmo. Além de você não usar `Objeto::Bola` mas sim `Bola` (que, se não me engano, também é erro semântico, mas não lembro bem), ainda por cima tentou atribuir valor a uma constante.

Resumindo, acho que você está interessado é em criar campos de objeto de classe, não criar enumeração. Se este é o caso, recomendo você fazer o que o amigo sugeriu, simplesmente troque a enumeração

`enum Objetos {Bola, Carrinho, Caixa, Dinamite};`

pela definição de campos de objeto

`int Bola , Carrinho , Caixa , Dinamite ;`

e então poderá setar seus valores. Espero ter esclarecido.